# How to prevent onNavigationItemSelected fires when the activity is launched?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-spinner

I want to use spinner in the action bar in my activity below is the onCreateOptionsMenu: I use [this tutorial](http://android-ed.blogspot.com/2013/04/adding-spinner-to-actionbarsherlock.html) to achieve this approach. My problem is when the activity is lunch, the onNavigationItemSelected method fires and the code on the switch/case run and the activity that I set for the position 0 opens. what should I do to prevent to run the switch/case when the activity is lunch?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 10)
    {
        mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner_data,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    }
    else
    {
        mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner_data,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    }
    ActionBar.OnNavigationListener mOnNavigationListener = new ActionBar.OnNavigationListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long itemId)
        {
            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    Intent searchIntent = new Intent(ActivitySearchBusiness.this, ActivityFindBusinessCity.class);
                    startActivity(searchIntent);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Intent dealsIntent = new Intent(ActivitySearchBusiness.this, ActivityDeals.class);
                    startActivity(dealsIntent);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Intent eventsIntent = new Intent(ActivitySearchBusiness.this, ActivityEvents.class);
                    startActivity(eventsIntent);
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    };
    actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, 

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the following code inside `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu)`:

....
....

Remove it and place it in your activity's `onCreate(Bundle)` method.

**Edit:**

Declare a global `boolean` variable:

```
boolean initializing = true;
```

Place the following code inside `onCreate(Bundle)`:

```
SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter;
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 10)
{
    mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner_data,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
}
else
{
    mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner_data,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
}
ActionBar.OnNavigationListener mOnNavigationListener = new ActionBar.OnNavigationListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long itemId)
    {

        if (initializing) {
            initializing = false;
        } else {             
            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    Intent searchIntent = new Intent(ActivitySearchBusiness.this, ActivityFindBusinessCity.class);
                    startActivity(searchIntent);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Intent dealsIntent = new Intent(ActivitySearchBusiness.this, ActivityDeals.class);
                    startActivity(dealsIntent);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Intent eventsIntent = new Intent(ActivitySearchBusiness.this, ActivityEvents.class);
                    startActivity(eventsIntent);
                    break;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
};
//actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, mOnNavigationListener);
getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, mOnNavigationListener);
```

Comment: Thank you but the problem did not solve. when the activity lunch the startActivity in first case runs.

Comment: Do not you have any idea?

Comment: I finally used the solution same as you, but really thank you I marked your answer

Comment: Thanks... This worked for me too.. I was breaking my head for the last 2 days.. Glad I found this...